# how to close position based on price movement

Tags: pine-script

I am struggling with exiting position based on current price difference from entry price point. Here is my attempt

```
ema200 = ema(close, 200)
diff = close - ema200
shortdiff = ema200 - close
long = shortdiff > 2
short = diff > 2 

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1000.0, when=long)
strategy.close("long", when=short)
strategy.exit("exit", "long", profit = 2000, loss = 1000)
```

I had to randomly pick `2000` and `1000` in order to achieve what I am looking for but instead what I am looking for is to take profit when the price reaches `$2` high or take a loss when the price reaches below `$1` from entry price. For example if there is open order at average price of `170`, I would like to take profit at `172` or take a loss at `169`

Answer (score 0):

You need the function to convert $$ (money) to points:

```
moneyToSLPoints(money) =>
    strategy.position_size !=0 ? (money / syminfo.pointvalue / abs(strategy.position_size)) / syminfo.mintick : na
```

[Here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/IHVPG6TS-Stop-loss-and-Take-Profit-in-example/) you can see how it works